# Flickity-view can't be edit (Flickity Plug-in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Test case: [Flickity Sample](https://codepen.io/jamy/pen/gbdWGJ?q=testimonial&limit=all&type=type-pens)

I'm using this kind of pen and i'm having trouble of editing the flickity-viewport.

I'm trying to make the height of the viewport to be

it's on my style.css

```
.flickity-viewport{
height:678px; <!--But this doesn't been recognize-->
}
```

on my flickity.min.css

```
.flickity-viewport{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 height: 635px
 }
```

but when im trying to edit on my style.css it's not working
[image: Image Sample Here]

I don't know where that `style="height:1228px;"` came from. Kindly help me please

Answer (score 1):

May be from script that value coming.

you can use !important method to your css and fix the problem.

```
.flickity-viewport{
  height:678px !important; 
 }
```

Comment: I fixed it using !important :) yeah sorry